# Proof of fourier expansion.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can we prove:

> $$\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \ln\left( { \cos }^{ 2 }x \right) =\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { (-1) }^{ k-1 } }{ k } \cos { (2kx) } -\ln( 2) } $$

I know this is the fourier expansion. But I don't know how to prove it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac { { (-1) }^{ k-1 } }{ k } \cos  (2kx)=$ real part of $-\dfrac{(-1)^k}k(e^{2ix})^k=-\dfrac{(-e^{2ix})^k}k $

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac { { (-1) }^{ k-1 } }{ k } \cos  (2kx)=$ real part of    $-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-e^{2ix})^k}k=-\ln(1+e^{2ix})$

$\ln(1+e^{2ix})=\ln(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})+\ln(e^{ix})$

$=\ln(2\cos x)+i(x+2n\pi) $ where $n$ is any integer

Now equate the real parts